# Cannot use Resource.resx file in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, resources, resx

I want my web application to not have strings hardcoded but in a resx file. And maybe later make it multilangual.

I've walked through every tutorial but none is working for me.

I created a `Resources` folder (also tried `App_GlobalResources`) and created a `Resources.resx` file.

I had to do this by creating a text file and renaming it because my `Add > New Item` menu did not have the `Assembly Resource File` template.

I changed the file's properties to this:

[image: Resources Properties]

And yet I cannot access it in my controllers with

```
using Resources;
```

or

```
using NAMESPACE.Resources;
```

or in my razor files with those two.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: See [Resource Files and ASP.NET MVC Projects](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx)

Comment: I've tried exactly that but the `Resources` cannot be found.